# Checkbox label with URL link in Semantic UI React

Tags: semantic-ui-react

Semantic UI React [Checkbox](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox) can be used like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Checkbox } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const TermsOfServiceCheckbox = () => (
  <Checkbox label='I accept the Terms of Service' />
)

export default TermsOfServiceCheckbox
```

How do I set the Checkbox label so that the text *Terms of Service* is a link to a URL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`label` prop implements the item shorthand, so you can also pass there:

```
<Checkbox label={<label><a href='/'>I accept the Terms of Service</a></label>} />
<Checkbox label={<label>I accept the <a href='/'>Terms of Service</a></label>} />
<Checkbox label={{ children: <a href='/'>I accept the Terms of Service</a> }} />
```

Comment: It only works with `<label>` element, like this: `<Checkbox label={<label>I accept the <a href='/>Terms of Service</a></label>}/>`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, I forgot that `Checkbox` requires `label` in markup. I checked code and updated answer. Thanks